# Discord.py event loop closed error when trying to load token from file

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So for safety reasons I'm trying to store my token in a separate token.txt file. I try to load the token from the file and run the bot with this code:

```
f = open("token.txt", "r")
token = f.readline()
f.close()
bot.run(token)
```

However I get a Runtime: Event loop is closed error.
This is not the case if I simply input the token directly like so `bot.run("token")`. If anyone has any tips on how to solve this it would be much appreciated.

Edit: I have already tried using the .strip() method on the token.

Comment: Does your `token.txt` have a `\n`?

Comment: Don't think so and I have already tried using the .strip() method on the token so if there was that should've fixed it but unfortunately it did not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for trying to help everyone. I unfortunately couldn't find a solution to the problem specifically, however I moved over to storing the token in a JSON file and reading that. This has solved the issue.

Comment: ok good, idk what the problem was but good u found a way

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a context manager?
with open(filename, "r") as file_:
token = file_.readline()

bot.run(token)

Comment: readline() brings it in a list form so, you should either do token = file_.read() or token = fole_.readline()    bot.run(token[0])

Answer (score 1):

use this i have tested and it works
the thing with readline is brings the txt file in a list. hence thats why the error

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='')

token_file = open('token.txt', 'r')
token = token_file.read()

client.run(str(token))
```

in readlines() ['token']
in read() - 'token'

Comment: That's not working on my end, I have checked the variables contents and it is definitely pulling in the right info, but for some bizarre reason I still get the error. It only seems to want to work when I plug the token into the code directly.

Comment: im not sure why it doesnt work for you but i tested this method and it works

Comment: Yeah I have no idea, I just switched to using a JSON file instead and it works perfectly now.